# how to get touch event on a body in Box2d(Java)

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx

I have various bodies rotated at some angle with the help of Box2d in libGDX. What I want is to destroy the body when I click on it, but the problem is that I am not able to get the area definition of the body so, that I can check whether my touch point lies inside the body or not. I tried using actor and its hit() method but its working only if I don`t rotate it, As far as I know , once I rotated the body , its bounds are not rotated . So, how can we check Touch event in a Body. 
*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the `touchDown` handler in the [libgdx Box2DTest](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-backend-android-livewallpaper/source/browse/gdx-backend-android-livewallpaper-example/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/box2d/Box2DTest.java?r=ba02aaf34a8ca07daa0c30493bab993067c652f9).  They use `World.QueryAABB` (AABB is "Axis-Aligned Bounding Box") to query which objects intersect a small bounding box around the the touch point, and then use the query callback to verify the actual touch point intersects the object in question.